# distinct uses of `impl Trait` result in different opaque types in rust

Tags: rust

I have defined two function to box the actix_web response like this:

```
pub fn box_actix_rest_response<T>(data: T) -> impl Responder where T: Serialize + Default{
    let res = ApiResponse {
        result: data,
        ..Default::default()
    };
    HttpResponse::Ok().json(res)
}

pub fn box_error_actix_rest_response <T>(data: T, result_code: String, msg: String) -> impl Responder where T: Serialize + Default {
    let res = ApiResponse {
        result: data,
        statusCode: "200".to_string(),
        resultCode: result_code,
        msg
    };
    HttpResponse::Ok().json(res)
}
```

one function wrapper the normal response and another wrapper the error response, but when I use this two funciton in the same outer level function like this:

```
pub fn create_file(add_req: &TexFileAddReq, login_user_info: &LoginUserInfo) -> impl Responder {
    let new_file = TexFileAdd::gen_tex_file(add_req, login_user_info);
    use crate::model::diesel::tex::tex_schema::tex_file as cv_work_table;
    use crate::model::diesel::tex::tex_schema::tex_file::dsl::*;
    let mut query = cv_work_table::table.into_boxed::<diesel::pg::Pg>();
    query = query.filter(
        cv_work_table::parent
            .eq(add_req.parent.clone())
            .and(cv_work_table::name.eq(add_req.name.clone()))
            .and(cv_work_table::file_type.eq(add_req.file_type.clone())),
    );
    let cvs = query.load::<TexFile>(&mut get_connection()).unwrap();
    if !cvs.is_empty() {
        return box_error_actix_rest_response("already exists", "ALREADY_EXISTS".to_owned(), "file/folder already exists".to_owned());
    }
    let result = diesel::insert_into(tex_file)
        .values(&new_file)
        .get_result::<TexFile>(&mut get_connection())
        .expect("failed to add new tex file or folder");
    let resp = box_actix_rest_response(result);
    return resp;
}
```

shows error:

```
mismatched types
expected opaque type `impl Responder` (opaque type at </Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/git/checkouts/rust_wheel-8476ff1b418e67f8/252bdd6/src/common/wrapper/actix_http_resp.rs:23:88>)
   found opaque type `impl Responder` (opaque type at </Users/xiaoqiangjiang/.cargo/git/checkouts/rust_wheel-8476ff1b418e67f8/252bdd6/src/common/wrapper/actix_http_resp.rs:15:47>)
distinct uses of `impl Trait` result in different opaque typesrustcClick for full compiler diagnostic
actix_http_resp.rs(23, 88): the expected opaque type
actix_http_resp.rs(15, 47): the found opaque type
file_service.rs(106, 81): expected `impl Responder` because of return type
```

It look like the two function return the different `Responder`, what should I do to fixed this issue? is it possible to use these two function like this?

Comment: if you replace the generic return type `impl Responder` by the concrete type  `HttpResponse` you actually return in both cases, does this help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you return a type `impl Trait` for a given trait, the actual underlying type is said to be opaque, that is, it exists, the compilers knows what it is, but it must be considered different from any other type in the current scope. This is similar to when you introduce generic types: even though (at monomorphization) the compiler knows the actual type, it behaves as is it had no information on it besides the trait constraints.

The reason for this is that each function's signature must be typechecked "on its own" (while taking into account the signatures of other functions). If you changed the actual return type of `box_actix_rest_response` into an other type that implements `Response`, it wouldn't change its signature, yet `create_file` could not typecheck.

Two opaque types from different sources *cannot* be unified, hence the error. What you want here is to write the actual underlying type rather than forcing the type to become opaque: in your case, it's `HttpResponse`:

```rust
pub fn box_actix_rest_response<T>(data: T) -> HttpResponse where T: Serialize + Default{
    let res = ApiResponse {
        result: data,
        ..Default::default()
    };
    HttpResponse::Ok().json(res)
}

pub fn box_error_actix_rest_response <T>(data: T, result_code: String, msg: String) -> HttpResponse where T: Serialize + Default {
    let res = ApiResponse {
        result: data,
        statusCode: "200".to_string(),
        resultCode: result_code,
        msg
    };
    HttpResponse::Ok().json(res)
}
```

Comment: Another, more important reason is design: `impl Trait` exists so we can change the type without breaking.

Comment: If the two opaque types couldn't be changed (e.g. they are in third party code or intentional design), they could be unified by casting them to trait objects (i.e. `dyn Response`). Using those requires an allocation and has some runtime overhead, but sometimes it's the tool to use.

Answer (score 0):

Consider also the library [auto_enums](https://lib.rs/crates/auto_enums), which allows you to return opaque types like this from the same function.